# Twitter auth 2.0 is not working in postman

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-api-v2

When I try to generate new access token in postman for twitter auth2.0. I get this error when I click on generat new token:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdsYl.png)

I have tried many ways to resolve it but am still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This steps will get an `Access Token` from Tweetter.

#### POST Endpoint

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials
```

`grant_type` is `client_credentials` by query parameter

[image]

#### Authorization

Select `Authorization` tab

Select `Basic Auth` combo box

Enter Username with `API Key`

Enter Password with `API Secret`

[image]

Those two value from Tweeter Developer Dashboard's project

```
https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard
```

[image]

#### Get Access Token

Finally, you can get the access token.

[image]

#### Assign Variable

If you want to using as variable of Postman,
Add this code in `Tests` section for calling V2 API.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData)
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", jsonData.access_token);

console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("access-token"))
```

[image]

Comment: No problem, Can you vote me? it will help to keep an answer. You can do even if 1 point.

Comment: Did that. It will only show once you have some more.

Comment: No, you can click up arrow in my answer, it will give a reputation 15 points to me. Try it thanks you.