# Twitter API timeline - one entire week

Tags: twitter, timeline, permanent

- I'm new to API and Twitter
- I managed to retrieve the 'normal' 20 Tweets (Status)
- Is there a way to retrieve a whole week at once?
- Or do I have to write a code that permanently calls 20 Tweets and append each after the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get whole week of tweet by Get User's lookup Tweet V2 API

OR

Get timeline for user by V1.1 API

#### [Tweet User's lookup V2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/introduction)

```
GET /2/users/{user id}/tweets
```

#### [get tweet time line](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) by V1.1 API

```
GET statuses/user_timeline
```

I will demo both with [Mr. Tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk) by Postman.

#### #1 Get access token in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216166/twitter-auth-2-0-is-not-working-in-postman/75216516#75216516)

This token support both V2 and V1.1 API call.

#### #2 Get Tweets one week by v2

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/44196397/tweets?max_results=20&start_time=2023-01-18T00:00:01Z&end_time=2023-01-25T00:00:01Z
```

[image]

If you want to more detail information for each tweet.
Add attribute option in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets) by Adding query parameters(like a `like count`, `create at` and so on)

[image]

#### #3 Get timeline, 20 Tweets by v1.1

Timeline API Two methods in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/introduction)

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/timelines/reverse_chronological
```

OR

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/tweets
```

Demo for get tweet with 2nd methods

```js
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=elonmusk&count=20
```

[image]

Both API needs access token assignment
[image]

Both API can be programming by node.js or Python [languages](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/sdks/overview).

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const API_KEY = '<your API Key>'
const API_KEY_SECRET = '<your API Secret>'

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
            data = '',
            config = {
                params: {
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: API_KEY,
                    password: API_KEY_SECRET
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.access_token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
};
const getUserId = async (username, token) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(
            url = `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/${username}`,
            config = {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                }
            }
        );
        // { data: { id: '44196397', name: 'Elon Musk', username: 'elonmusk' } }
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.data.id)
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
};

const getTweetTimeline = async (user_id, start_date, end_date, token) => {
    try {
        const tweets = [];
        let index = 1
        let next_token = 'start'
        while (next_token != null) {
            let url = `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/${user_id}/tweets?start_time=${start_date}&end_time=${end_date}&tweet.fields=created_at&max_results=20`
            if (next_token != 'start') {
                url = `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/${user_id}/tweets?start_time=${start_date}&end_time=${end_date}&tweet.fields=created_at&max_results=20&pagination_token=${next_token}`
            }
            const resp = await axios.get(
                url = url,
                config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    }
                }
            );
            for(const item of resp.data.data) {
                tweets.push({
                    index : index,
                    created_at: item.created_at,
                    text: item.text,
                    id : item.id
                })
                index = index + 1
            }
            next_token = resp.data.meta.next_token
        }
        return Promise.resolve(tweets)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
}

getToken()
    .then(token => {
        console.log(token);
        getUserId('elonmusk', token)
            .then(user_id => {
                getTweetTimeline(user_id,'2023-02-05T00:00:00Z','2023-02-11T23:59:59Z', token)
                    .then(tweets => {
                        for(const tweet of tweets) {
                            console.log(tweet)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.message);
            });

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

Result
[image]

```
node get-tweet.js > result.json
```

[image]

#### Update for My Time line using Python with [`tweepy`](https://www.tweepy.org/) library.

I will use OAuth 2.0 App Only (center column), with my-user name (or other name - both supports) and get tweens during 30 days (exclude, retweets, replies)
[Tweet V2 `timeline`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/v2-authentication-mapping) API

```
GET /2/users/:id/tweets
```

[image]

The `tweepy` call that API intently in [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html)

Tweepy's API `Client.get_users_tweets()` will call Tweep V2 API's `GET /2/users/:id/tweets`

[image]

Detail parameter is in [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets)

Token from Developer [Dashboard](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal)

[image]

#### Python Demo Code

```py
import tweepy

def get_all_tweets(user_name):
    bearer_token ='<your App Bearer Token>' # From https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

    user = client.get_user(username = user_name)
    user_id = user.data.id
    userTweets = []
    count = 0
    limit = 1000
    pagination_token = None
    start_time = '2023-01-01T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    end_time   = '2023-01-31T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    while count < limit:
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(
            id = user_id,
            exclude = ['retweets','replies'],
            pagination_token = pagination_token,
            start_time = start_time,
            end_time = end_time,
            max_results = 100)
        if 'next_token' in tweets.meta.keys():
            if (tweets.meta['next_token']) is not None:
                pagination_token = tweets.meta['next_token']
            else:
                pagination_token = None
        else:
            pagination_token = None
        if tweets.data is not None:
            for tweet in tweets.data:
                count += 1
                userTweets.append({
                    "id": tweet.id,
                    "test": tweet.text
                })
        if pagination_token is None:
            break
    return userTweets, count
# user_name can assign your tweet name
user_name = 'elonmusk'
[tweets, count] = get_all_tweets(user_name)

print(count)
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet_url = f"https://twitter.com/{user_name}/status/{tweet['id']}"
    print(tweet)
    print(tweet_url)
```

Run it

```
python get-tweet.py
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Bench Vue.

Questions:
- Do I get all the tweets with use_timeline or only the ones posted by myself? 
- If I don't use Postman but an IDE the code would be:
week_timeline = api.user_timeline()
print(week_timeline)

Many thanks and happy weekend!

Comment: @Picnic, There are many way to get tilmeline, your point is Tweepy V1 method. I added my answer by V2 user id API. It can get all of any user's tweet for some period. You are also happy weekend!

Comment: Hi everybody. Thank you very much for your help. I don't want to extract tweets from specific users. I need MY timeline for a certain time period. I guess for this I need api.search_30_day(). Do you agree? PS: I don't use Postman, please show me your result in Python code.

Comment: No problem, don't forget vote me. You can vote by click up arrow in my answer.

Comment: It was actually another question of mine :-) Can you answer it?

Comment: What is another question?

Comment: I don't want to extract tweets from specific users. I need MY timeline for a certain time period. I guess for this I need api.search_30_day(). Do you agree? PS: I don't use Postman, please show me your result in Python code.

Comment: @Picnic, I added Python Timeline Demo by `tweepy` for getting 30 days timeline. The user name is general , you can use your tweet name or other name.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very useful for me. That's very kind of you!

Comment: No problem, don't forget vote to me. You can click up arrow in my answer. It will be help to keep answer to every one. Thanks!

Comment: Did that, pushed the up arrow!

Comment: You clicked twice it. It means no point to me. You click again the answer will turn to green colored check box and give me 15 points. Can try it again?

Comment: Hope it worked now. Can you tell?

Comment: I tried to follow and understand your code. Could you help me with '[userTweets, count] = get_all_tweets(user_name)'? You call the function with get_all_tweets(user_name). But what is [userTweets, count]? A list?

Comment: Those are return two values from `def get_all_tweets(user_name):` function.
The end of line of function is `return userTweets, count`. First item is user's tweets data. It is appended by `userTweets.append`. Second item is number of tweet. So [userTweets, count] multiple return values from function and assign new variable.  

So it means  assign both value , userTweets <- userTweets  and  count <- count

This [tutorial](https://pythonbasics.org/multiple-return/) help to understand.

Comment: I posted a new question in order to vote you again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75678392/twitter-api-call-several-user-names-with-python Could you please have a look?

Comment: I answer your new question for multiple users.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bench Vue. I saw it, it works, i pushed the arrow up :-)

Comment: @Picnic, Thanks you so much. Now you got more than 15 points, Can you up vote again. It will raise 10 more points to me.

Comment: @Picnic, Thanks, I got 10 more points. One more this answer also possible 10 more up points. Thanks!

Comment: I posted a new question regarding keyword search in Twitter API. Maybe you can help again...

Comment: I will look at your new question.