# How can I call several user_names in the Twitter API?

Tags: function, api, twitter, append, twitterapi-python

I could successfully get the data of a user in Python by `get_all_tweets(user_name)`. Now I would like to retrieve data from several users in the same code.

I tried to copy the same code and append it to the code. Instead of `user_name` I used `user_name1`, I also tried to change all the other variables to `...1`. The list for user_name is still produced. The list for `user_name1` not.

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
import time

def get_all_tweets(user_name):
    bearer_token ='XXX'
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

    user = client.get_user(username = user_name)
    user_id = user.data.id
    userTweets = []
    count = 0
    limit = 3000
    pagination_token = None
    start_time = '2023-03-01T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    end_time   = '2023-03-02T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    while count < limit:
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(
            id = user_id,
            exclude = ['retweets','replies'],
            tweet_fields = ['created_at','public_metrics'],
            pagination_token = pagination_token,
            start_time = start_time,
            end_time = end_time,
            max_results = 100)
        if 'next_token' in tweets.meta.keys():
            if (tweets.meta['next_token']) is not None:
                pagination_token = tweets.meta['next_token']
            else:
                pagination_token = None
        else:
            pagination_token = None
        if tweets.data is not None:
            for tweet in tweets.data:
                count += 1
                userTweets.append({
                "id": tweet.id,
                "test": tweet.text,
                "date": tweet.created_at,
                "public":tweet.public_metrics
                })
        if pagination_token is None:
            break
    return userTweets, count

# user_name can assign your tweet name
user_name = 'Weltwoche'
[userTweets, count] = get_all_tweets(user_name)

def get_all_tweets(user_name1):
    bearer_token ='XXX'
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

    user = client.get_user(username = user_name1)
    user_id = user.data.id
    userTweets1 = []
    count1 = 0
    limit = 3000
    pagination_token = None
    start_time = '2023-03-01T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    end_time   = '2023-03-02T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    while count1 < limit:
        tweets1 = client.get_users_tweets(
            id = user_id,
            exclude = ['retweets','replies'],
            tweet_fields = ['created_at','public_metrics'],
            pagination_token = pagination_token,
            start_time = start_time,
            end_time = end_time,
            max_results = 100)
        if 'next_token' in tweets1.meta.keys():
            if (tweets1.meta['next_token']) is not None:
                pagination_token = tweets1.meta['next_token']
            else:
                pagination_token = None
        else:
            pagination_token = None
        if tweets1.data is not None:
            for tweet1 in tweets1.data:
                count1 += 1
                userTweets1.append({
                "id": tweet.id,
                "test": tweet.text,
                "date": tweet.created_at,
                "public":tweet.public_metrics
                })
        if pagination_token is None:
            break
    return userTweets1, count1

# user_name can assign your tweet name
user_name1 = 'Blick'
[userTweets1, count1] = get_all_tweets(user_name1)

print(count)
for tweet in userTweets:
    print(tweet)
print(count1)
for tweet1 in userTweets1:
    print(tweet1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using user array and call same function.

```py
import tweepy

def get_all_tweets(user_name):
    bearer_token ='your bearer token' # From https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

    user = client.get_user(username = user_name)
    user_id = user.data.id
    userTweets = []
    count = 0
    limit = 3000
    pagination_token = None
    start_time = '2023-01-01T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    end_time   = '2023-01-31T00:00:00Z' # YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
    while count < limit:
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(
            id = user_id,
            exclude = ['retweets','replies'],
            pagination_token = pagination_token,
            start_time = start_time,
            end_time = end_time,
            max_results = 100)
        if 'next_token' in tweets.meta.keys():
            if (tweets.meta['next_token']) is not None:
                pagination_token = tweets.meta['next_token']
            else:
                pagination_token = None
        else:
            pagination_token = None
        if tweets.data is not None:
            for tweet in tweets.data:
                count += 1
                userTweets.append({
                    "id": tweet.id,
                    "test": tweet.text
                })
        if pagination_token is None:
            break
    return userTweets, count

# you can make users array in here
user_names = ["elonmusk", "BarackObama"]
for user_name in user_names:
    [tweets, count] = get_all_tweets(user_name)

    for tweet in tweets:
        tweet_url = f"https://twitter.com/{user_name}/status/{tweet['id']}"
        print(tweet)
        print(tweet_url)

    print(user_name + "'s tweets count is " + str(count))
```

Result

```
elonmusk's tweets count is 78
...
BarackObama's tweets count is 26
```

[image]

Comment: I still use your Python code above - thanks again.
But I struggle that it doesn't attribute the {user_name} well. 
user_names = ['Blickch', 'tagesanzeiger', 'Handelszeitung', '20min', 'NZZ']
Although the tweets are from different user_names in the list above it always takes 'NZZ', therefore the last one out of the list.
Strangely when I click on the link printed in the output it redirects automatically to the right user_name in the above list.
Do you know why? Could it be because of an indent?

Comment: Did you see my question already?

Comment: @Picnic, Sorry no response your question. Can my code still work after Twitter changing license policy from Elivated to Free license? I think Free account only allow create twitte API(Only Tweet creation). Other API is not allow, is correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I wasn't much active lately since - exactly - the Twitter API is supposed only to work with posting. And tonight I just tested your code on API. Indeed: unfortunately when I run it it provides error: Forbidden 403 Could I help you with this answer?

Comment: After change the API strategy from Twitter company, I can't test at all. I decided to leave twitter API testing and answer.

Comment: Sad fact, yes: I also have to find other ways to go on with my project :-(